# ubuntu install black screen (nomodeset not working)

Tags: system-installation, nomodeset

I'm having trouble with installing 'Ubuntu desktop 18.04 LTS' on my new computer.
It has no OS, and I was attempting to install Ubuntu via USB.

After selecting 'Try Ubuntu without installing' at grub, the screen turns black, unable to check the installation process.
I even tried adding `nomodeset` behind `quiet splash` with no avail.

Now I'm wondering whether it's the motherboard/graphic-card problem. Below is my computer's spec. Any advice would be helpful!

=================================

cpu : intel core i9-7960x

motherboard : asus tuf x299 mark1

graphic-card : geforce gtx 1650 udv oc d5 4gb

Comment: `nomodeset` **should** work. Make sure you edited correctly and you can even try it instead of "quiet splash" as it may show error messages that wouldn't otherwise appear. Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: When you boot you Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (*yy.mm* in format being the year.month of release) a person-in-circle & keyboard-in-rectangle appear, press a key at that point, then select check-install-media to ensure the download & write to thumb-drive was flawless.  It's good insurance in my opinion, and what I'd do first.

Comment: @guiverc Useful advice but the animation you mentioned only appears in BIOS/Legacy. The OP is clearly booting in UEFI mode (as it should be). The option to check media should appear in the menu as well though.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but I solved the problem by installing ubuntu 1.9.04, not 1.8.04 LTS version....

Doesn't the 2 have the same system requirement?? I swear the nomodeset didn't work with the 1.8.04 LTS image....